# Throwing exception with message from regex match

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find unused merge fields in an email and throw the field that wasn't supported by the parser. The format is [MERGEFIELD]. All capital letters within brackets.

I Then want to throw the value of the first unsupported merge field in the text.

```
            if (Regex.IsMatch(email.Body, @"\[[A-Z]+\]"))
        {
            var regexobj = new Regex(@"\[[A-Z]+\]");
            var regexBody = regexobj.Match(email.Body).Groups[1].Value;
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unsupported Merge Field:"+ regexBody );
        }
```

Right now I'm getting the exception, but there only message is "Unsupported Merge Field:"

Comment: Why use a regex at all?  It's overkill when you can simply use `String.Contains("[MERGEFIELD")` or `String.IndexOf("[MERGEFIELD]")`.  It serves only to overcomplicate the problem.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear, I'm using about 25 different keywords in the mergefield (such as [FNAME] and [LNAME]). I want it to find any that didn't end up getting parsed in the format [CAPITALLETTERSINHERE]

Comment: @Subliminy So you want to find anything that looks like capital letters surrounded by brackets?

Comment: yeah, and then to throw that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the value of (capturing) group 1 (matched content in parenthesis), which does not exist in your expression.

Maybe you want to use an expression like this instead:

```
\[([A-Z]+)\]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parenthesis in order to capture.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

See also, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

I like using named capture groups which are in the format of
(?< name > subexpression), which will let you access the capture by name instead of by index.

Something like the below (hand coded)

```
    if (Regex.IsMatch(email.Body, @"\[[A-Z]+\]"))
    {
        var regexobj = new Regex(@"(?<unsupportedField>\[[A-Z]+\])");
       foreach(Match match in regexobj.Matches(email.Body))
       {
           string unsupported = match.Groups["unsupportedField"].Value
           //aggregate these then throw
       }
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unsupported Merge Field:"+ regexBody );
    }
```

Comment: the naming capture groups is really cool. I didn't know about it, thanks.